# WP7-Control to enter numeric data?

Tags: controls, windows-phone-7

I've got a WP7 app where I need to enter large numeric data (6 digits and more) - is there some kind of advanced numeric control to enter large numbers comfortably?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By comfortably, do you mean the keyboard that comes up?  Or that you don't want to use a keyboard at all?

In Silverlight, I believe that one way to set the type of keyboard is set the scope of the input for the TextBox... so in XAML:

```
<TextBox InputScope=”Number” …/>
```

or for a phone keypad

```
<TextBox InputScope=”TelephoneNumber” …/>
```

Comment: I didn't think about the keyboard, more about something like the datepicker where you can slide individual sets onscreen.

Comment: But to be able to set the inputscope is a great start in general, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This post seems to outline a cleaner way to limit input to numerics only than what I previously wrote (deleting that).

[Making TextBox Numbers Only for Windows Phone 7](http://www.atleyhunter.com/2010/11/12/making-textbox-numbers-only-for-windows-phone-7/)